# Freebsd 12 error when use pip install

Tags: python, freebsd, pip

No experience with Freebsd, but I need to write and run a script. Can't install python-ldap or another lib.

An error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install python-ldap ld-elf.so.1: /lib/libc.so.7: version FBSD_1.6 required by /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 not found
```

This library is in the  /usr/local/lib/ folder,

```
# ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep py
libpython2.7.so
libpython2.7.so.1
libpython2.7.so.1-gdb.py
libpython3.7m.so
libpython3.7m.so.1.0
```

But if use ldconfig -r

```
# ldconfig -r | grep py
        91:-lpython2.7.1 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1
```

I dont know how "rescan" ldconfig. I need your help.

Comment: Please [edit] in the specific version of FreeBSD 12 you're using. Also, please include the output of `file /usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

Answer (score 0):

FBSD_1.6 refers to FreeBSD 13. What version are you running? Did you install packages for 13 on a FreeBSD 12 installation? Sounds like upgrading FreeBSD will solve the issue.

[FreeBSD Symbol versioning](https://wiki.freebsd.org/SymbolVersioning)

You can see the current version running like this

```
freebsd-version
uname -mrs
```

Comment: Hello. Maybe you know how to install old packages for fbsd_1.5?

Comment: hello, my answer is related to the issue and this is how it will be solved.